# Footer columns not working

Tags: html, css

I have a footer inside this i have 2 divs column 1 and column 2

I added a max width and display inline hoping the result would be like this:

```
-----------------------------
|aaaaaaaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaaaaaaa|
|aaaaaaaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaaaaaaa|
|aaaaaaaaaaaaa|aaaaaaaaaaaaa|
-----------------------------
```

But when i add a long string everything goes out of place i even added break-word, did i miss something here?

HTML-Part:

```
<div id='generated_footer_date' style='background-color:$backgroundColor; color:$fontColor; opacity: $opacity; height:auto;'>
    <div class='column1of2'>ddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfd</div>
    <div class='column2of2'>column2of2ddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfdddfd</div>
</div>
```

CSS-Part:

```
.column1of2 {
    display: inline;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px !important;
    height: auto;
    padding-right: 20%;
}

.column2of2 {
   display:inline;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   height:auto;
   width:200px;
}

#generated_footer_date {
   color:#ffffff;
   background-color:black;
   opacity: 1;
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
   padding-top:15px;
   padding-bottom:15px;
   word-wrap: break-word; 
   height:50px auto;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wzfyj2z4/1/

Comment: You need to use `display: inline-block` for both columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, inline elements don't work as you expected. Needs to be `display: inline-block` all columns.

The other side is `word-wrap`, that you need `word-break : break-all`.

With these two changes it works perfectly:

https://jsfiddle.net/wzfyj2z4/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this **CSS**,

```
.column1of2 {
 float:left;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 height: auto;
 width: 200px !important;
 height: auto;
 padding-right: 20%;
}

.column2of2 {
float:left;
word-wrap: break-word;
  height:auto;
  width:200px;
}

#generated_footer_date {
float:left;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:black;
opacity: 1;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
word-wrap: break-word; 
height:50px auto;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kushan/pyf5s0L8/

Comment: Why `float`? That's not a solution, is a totally change of layout.

Comment: No. its not change the layout. check my answer https://jsfiddle.net/kushan/pyf5s0L8/

Answer (score 1):

Use The below css  for both class.Hope It Helps. . . .

```
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
```